# Why it does not show the output in while loop?

Tags: c, loops, nodes

I am trying to write a C code. It works correctly until GPA, but it does not continue and terminates after when I input the GPA. I do not understand its reason. What should I do to fix this problem?

Here is my codes:

```
NODE* create_list()
{
    NODE *first, *temp = 0, *newNode;
    first = 0;
    int choice = 1;
    head = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to allocate memory.");
    }
    else
    {

        printf("Do you want to continue(Type 0 or 1)?\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &choice);
        while (choice)
        {

            newNode = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
            struct studentType studen;
            printf("Enter the data student Id:\n");
            scanf_s("%d", &studen.id);
            printf("Enter the data student Name:\n");
            scanf_s("%s", studen.name);
            printf("Enter the data student GPA:\n");
            scanf_s("%d", &studen.GPA);
            newNode->stud = studen; // Link data field of newNode with data
            newNode->ptr = NULL; // Link address field of newNode with NULL

            temp->ptr = newNode; // Link previous node i.e. temp to the newNode

            temp = temp->ptr;
            printf("Do you want to continue(Type 0 or 1)?\n");
            scanf_s("%d", &choice);


        }
    }
    temp->ptr = 0;


    return first;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*temp = 0
```

Here, you initialize `temp` by NULL pointer.

Then you try to access the `ptr` inside it without the initialization:

```
 temp->ptr = newNode;
```

So, you have to initialize `temp` before working with this variable.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did it as you said, but it still does not work. I do not know how can i fix it

Comment: What do you mean when you said `it still does not work` (it raises the error or something else)? What did you change ?

Comment: The program terminates, and doesn't show the output. It does not give an error. 

I did it like that, is it wrong?

temp=0;
newNode->stud = studen;
newNode->ptr = NULL;
temp->ptr = newNode;
temp = temp->ptr;

Comment: when you assign `temp = 0`, it means `temp = NULL`. Try to allocate `temp` or declare `temp` as `NODE temp`